# How can I show a specific product on a certain position in my WooCommerce shop?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

**My question**

I try to show some specific products on my shop but my client what to decide at which position which product should be showed.

Like if product ID is 29961, I want to show it on 6th position on my shop product page and then another one on 12th position.

**Visual example**

( )( )( )( )

( )(*)( )( )

( )( )( )(*)

**What I have tried so far**

I found "[Rearrange Products Manually or In Custom Order in WooCommerce](https://woorkup.com/rearrange-products-manually-custom-order-woocommerce/)" but to use that I have to remove my shop sorting filter sort by most recent products.

That can be achieved by selecting sorting method to "custom + naming" from WooCommerce archive settings and then assign a menu order number to that specific product according to position you want to display at.

But in my case I want to use main sorting method "sort by most recent" and show targeted product on selected position.

Comment: "_I have searched for solution but couldn't find one for my product_"
what have you tried so far? can you add the attempts to your question?

Comment: @7uc1f3r i edited the question and the method that i found can be seen here...[link](https://woorkup.com/rearrange-products-manually-custom-order-woocommerce/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Woocommerce shortcode for this:

[products ids="2380, 2359, 5643, 7658, 9876, 29961" ]

Comment: can you please explain what kind of short-code are you talking about?

Comment: Hi Hassan - In the above example you would copy and paste the code [products ids="add product ids here"] in the text area (not the code area) You want to separate each product id with a comma. I made up ids and then put your example as 6th. This would give you complete control over the order of your products. I would also turn off the "Shop" page to use this code. Under Woocommerce > Settings click on the products tab and make sure the SHOP dropdown is set to blank. (you click the x on the current page) Then go paste the shortcode in on the page where the shop was.

Comment: You will have to add new product ids to the shortcode as you create them - but again this will give you full control of where these products are. So if you want to put a new product first but keep 29961 as the 6th - this will do the trick.

Comment: hi there... thanks for your reply....!
but i want to keep my other shop products as they are and main sorting method to sort by most recent and only want to change position of certain products. Your method would disturb my shop page other layout settings.
I want to show two off my product with stock over 10 to show on first shop page and similarly next two product with stock over 10 on second page and so on...
Anything else that you would recommend?